# Xamarin Forms Iconize, IconToolbarItem disappears

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I have an issue with Iconize, I want to display a shoppingcart icon and a badget count within the IconNavigation toolbar.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <iconize:IconToolbarItem Icon="fa-shopping-cart" Priority="0"></iconize:IconToolbarItem>
    <!-- also tested -->
    <!--<iconize:IconToolbarItem Text="{Binding CartCount}" Priority="1"></iconize:IconToolbarItem>-->
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding CartCount}" Priority="1" ></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

after incrementing the count, the icon disappears immediately. (only on Android)

It seems that the cause is the text binding and I don't know how to fix it.

Any proposed solutions ?